# Using MLE to determine peak of distribution of daily count data

Tags: r, distribution, data-fitting

I'm trying to estimate the date of peak abundance for a migratory period from point counts. A previous study has used the following methods:

> Fitted a truncated normal distribution to trapping densities per 5-day interval. Used an iterative algorithm to obtain the maximum-likelihood estimate of the mean of the distribution (corresponding to the estimated peak passage) and its standard error.

I can work out how to do most of this, but I'm stuck on perhaps the simplest problem. My data is in the following format: A column for date and a column for the count for that date.

In other programs I can use the date for my distribution and the count as a frequency of the distribution. This will allow me to fit a distribution to the counts.

I cannot figure out how to do this in R however. Functions such as fitdistr or dnorm only allow a vector string.

Are there any functions that allow me to have a vector for frequency and a vector for the variable of interest and to use that to fit a distribution?

The data looks like this:

> head(FR.Counts)
>
> Day.of.Year    Count
>
> ```
>      112     13780
>
>      122     76727
>
>      123     55458
>
>      125     36746
>
>      126     30079
>
>      127     20715
> ```

With 112-127 being day of year and the rest is the counts.

Thanks

Comment: are you willing to post a small reproducible example?

Comment: I've added a few lines of the data above. I've since found fit.dist() which might work, but doesn't run with the current version of R